# Enable NotificationListenerService not showing for app in Settings - Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, notification-listener

I am a bit new to android development and was trying to make an application which listens to new notifications appearing on my device but when I go to enable the settings using the following statement, I don't get my app name in the settings. I have gone through the [Android developers NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) and added the service `AndroidMainfest`. I open the settings activity by this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
```

The following is my `NotificationListener class`

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private final String Notification_Settings = "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startActivity(new Intent(Notification_Settings));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        Log.i(TAG, title + " " + text);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return super.onBind(i);
    }
}
```

And finally, I call the service in the main activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationListener.class);
startService(i);
```

I could not figure out what had I missed. Please help me. Thank you!

**Edit:**

Service in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_lISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: If it doesn't show up in settings it means it's misconfigured in manifest, add your manifest declaration to question

Comment: Okay Sure will do that

Comment: It looks fine to me, only other issue I know is you might be trying to use low ram device which is not allowed to run notification listener service

Comment: But it works for the other apps

Comment: Thank you for your help but i just noticed it now that the 'L' in the `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_lISTENER_SERVICE">` is a small one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Pawel I checked the manifest and noticed the 'L' in the

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_lISTENER_SERVICE">
                                                         ^
```

is a small one.